# PostgreSQL : Change column values based on another column value using some condition in same table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and want to replace the column value with value from other column value based on some condition.

```js
 
+---------------------+
| Cntry | Code | Value |    
+---------------------+
| US  | C11  | A     | 
| US  | C12  | B     |
| US  | C13  | C     |
| US  | C14  | D     |
| US  | C15  | E     |
| UK  | C11  | A     | 
| UK  | C12  | B     |
| UK  | C13  | C     |
| UK  | C14  | D     |
| UK  | C15  | E     |

+---------------------+
```

I want to replace the value of C14 based on the value of C11 based on Cntry

So my output should be like this.

```html
+---------------------+
| Cntry | Code | Value |
+---------------------+
| US  | C11  | A     | 
| US  | C12  | B     |
| US  | C13  | C     |
| US  | C14  | A     |<====Repalce with C11 for US
| US  | C15  | E     |
| UK  | C11  | G     | 
| UK  | C12  | B     |
| UK  | C13  | C     |
| UK  | C14  | G     |<====Repalce with C11 for UK
| UK  | C15  | E     |

+---------------------+
```

Is there anyway to do this in postgresql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    cntry varchar NULL,
    code varchar NULL,
    value varchar NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('US', 'C11', 'A');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('US', 'C12', 'B');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('US', 'C13', 'C');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('US', 'C14', 'D');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('US', 'C15', 'E');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('UK', 'C11', 'G');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('UK', 'C12', 'B');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('UK', 'C13', 'C');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('UK', 'C14', 'D');
INSERT INTO table1 (cntry, code, value) VALUES('UK', 'C15', 'E');
```

Sample query:

```
select 
    t1.cntry, 
    t1.code, 
    case when t2.value is not null then t2.value else t1.value end as "value"
from table1 t1  
left join (
    select 
        cntry, 
        'C14' as code, 
        value 
    from table1
    where code = 'C11'
) t2 on t1.cntry = t2.cntry and t1.code = t2.code 

-- Result: 
cntry   code    value
US      C11     A
US      C12     B
US      C13     C
US      C14     A
US      C15     E
UK      C11     G
UK      C12     B
UK      C13     C
UK      C14     G
UK      C15     E
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually change the contents of your table, then an [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) query will do the trick.

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET code = 'C11' 
 WHERE code = 'C14'`
```

For obvious reasons, you should be super careful with UPDATE queries. There are a couple of ways to avoid mistakes that I sometimes use:

1. Try a SELECT statement first to get the rows I think I want to change. If this looks good, then edit the query to change SELECT to UPDATE
2. Make a copy of the table. Try your update on the copy. If you're happy with the results, try the query on the original table. Use [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) to create table (`SELECT * INTO tablecopy FROM mytable`) and then [DROP TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html) (`DROP tablecopy`) on the copy.